# Variable length item when inserting as a line (conforming to table layout)

Tags: html, css

This is an advice question. I have created a scrollable div, it looks like this:

[image]

I will be inserting `<p></p>`s here in place of `<p>sadsa</p>` that will have four items in them: **categorization, y_i, RC(F_i), RC(tilde(F)_j)**. The idea is to make them all align nicely in this div. I have not come across a similar problem before. The last three (**y_i, RC(F_i), RC(tilde(F)_j**) are not the problem, as these are numbers and will be of fixed width (so even something like margins can be used to place them correctly. However the categorization string can be of any length. One solution is to make it fixed length, and then use margins for **y_i**, etc. However, this won't work, because if the user expands the window, the encompassing div will get larger, but the field for categorization will be of fixed width. Has anyone come across such a problem before?

I will be grateful for any suggestions. Perhaps I could use a table for this?

Here is the code for the scrollable div for you (this is not exactly what I have, but it will do as a rough replica of this screenshot):

```css
.descriptive-data {
    position:fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 44%;
    bottom: 20px;
    top:20px;
}

.table-header-div {
    position:relative;
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}

.margin-left-06em {
    margin-left: 0.6em;
}

.spans-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 12px;
    float: right;
}

.table-header-hr {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
    top: 25px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.scrollable-details {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 10px;
    background: red;
}

// https://codepen.io/GhostRider/pen/GHaFw
.style-2::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.style-2::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 12px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.style-2::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 background-color: #F4F7F7;
}
```

```html
<div class="descriptive-data">
 
      <div class="table-header-div">
          <span class="spans-wrapper">
              <span>y_i</span>
              <span class="margin-left-06em">f_i</span>
              <span class="margin-left-06em">tilde_f_j</span>
          </span>
      </div>
      <hr class="table-header-hr">
 

  <div class="scrollable-details style-2">
      <p>sadsa</p>
      <p>sadsa</p>
      <p>sadsa</p>
      <p>sadsa</p>
      <p>sadsa</p>
      <p>sadsa</p>
      <p>sadsa</p>
      <p>sadsa</p>
      <p>sadsa</p>
      <p>sadsa</p>
      <p>sadsa</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for this. However, without a _real_ example of the html you _intend_ to use, I don't know if we can help you further.

Comment: ok. let me try to get it here. This code editor was extremely slow for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recommend you to use table. the case for wot they have being created:

```css
.fixed_header{
    width: 400px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.fixed_header tbody{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.fixed_header thead tr {
   display: block;
}

.fixed_header thead {
  background: black;
  color:#fff;
}

.fixed_header th, .fixed_header td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table class="fixed_header">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 2-0</td>
      <td>row 2-1</td>
      <td>row 2-2</td>
      <td>row 2-3</td>
      <td>row 2-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 3-0</td>
      <td>row 3-1</td>
      <td>row 3-2</td>
      <td>row 3-3</td>
      <td>row 3-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 4-0</td>
      <td>row 4-1</td>
      <td>row 4-2</td>
      <td>row 4-3</td>
      <td>row 4-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 5-0</td>
      <td>row 5-1</td>
      <td>row 5-2</td>
      <td>row 5-3</td>
      <td>row 5-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 6-0</td>
      <td>row 6-1</td>
      <td>row 6-2</td>
      <td>row 6-3</td>
      <td>row 6-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: yeah. I think this will work, and I will then set a fixed width of each td in the tr....

Comment: hmm. I will still have a problem with the expanding window. This alleviates the issue of aligning the elements. But does solve the problem with the window resizing, because the width would stay the same. I will try to use ems/%. Let me check

Comment: I'm glad. Пожалуйста!)